# Why won't this stack properly display?

Tags: c++

I have to write a program to find the prime factorization of a number. For example, if the number is **3960**, the prime factors are **11 5 3 3 2 2 2**. When I run the program, that isn't the output you get. What's wrong with my code? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

#include "Stack.h"

int main()
{
int i;
int n;
int d;
Stack s;
   cout << "Stack created.  Empty? " << boolalpha << s.empty() << endl;



int num;
int div;
    cout<<"Enter a number to know its prime factor: "<<endl;
    cin >> num;

    cout << "\nThe prime factors of "<<num<<" are: \n\n" << endl;

    div = 2;

    while(num!=0){
        if(num%div!=0)
            div = div + 1;
        else {
            num = num / div;
            s.push(div);
            if(num==1)
              break;
        }

s.display(cout);

    }
}
```

Comment: Well what is the output you get?

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place, and why are you mixing `printf` and `cout`?

Comment: What output *do* you get?

Comment: You need to post the code for `Stack` and maybe we can help you

Comment: @Karl I'm sorry, but I rolled back your edit because the bad formatting is the root cause of the problem

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - No worries :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the stack within the calculation loop. The call to `s.display(cout)` needs to be placed outside one level of braces.

Your code looks like this:

```
    while(num!=0){
        if(num%div!=0)
            div = div + 1;
        else {
            num = num / div;
            s.push(div);
            if(num==1)
              break;
        }

s.display(cout);

    }
```

Yuch! Format it properly and it is:

```
while(num!=0){
    if(num%div!=0)
        div = div + 1;
    else {
        num = num / div;
        s.push(div);
        if(num==1)
          break;
    }
    s.display(cout);
}
```

which is clearly not what you want. You want:

```
while(num!=0){
    if(num%div!=0)
        div = div + 1;
    else {
        num = num / div;
        s.push(div);
        if(num==1)
          break;
    }
}
s.display(cout);
```

This will hopefully teach you to indent your code properly.

We don't know what your `Stack` class is, but this code certainly extracts the prime factors correctly and only prints them once!

I'm also not sure why you are using your own stack class here. You can perfectly well use `std::vector`. Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> stack;
    int num;
    int div;

    std::cout << "Enter a number to know its prime factor: ";
    std::cin >> num;
    std::cout << "\nThe prime factors of " << num << " are: \n\n" << std::endl;
    div = 2;
    while (num > 1){
        if (num%div != 0)
            div++;
        else {
            num /= div;
            stack.push_back(div);
        }
    }

    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator iter = stack.begin(); iter != stack.end(); ++iter)
        std::cout << *iter << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. And I apologize for the sloppy code.

Comment: It really pays to get indentation right. Programming is hard enough at the best of times!!